# Weight for Samples on SVM (Support Vector Machine)

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, sample, weights

there is a option `sample_weight` in `fit(X[, y, sample_weight])` function (*OneClassSVM, sklearn library*).

If I use the option `sample_weight` , I might give some weight to some point(that are likely to be more normal points), right?

Otherwise, what does mean the `sample_weight`?

link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.score_samples

Comment: Possibly the weights are combined into the loss function, so that the method minimises the weighted loss.  One example may be where, instead of having very large numbers of individual cases, you instead have fewer distinct cases but the frequency of each distinct case is known and you use the frequencies as weights.  Alternatively, perhaps  you may associate the costs of misclassification into wrong classes as varying and you weight the classes differently so that the loss function penalises different types of errors by different amounts